# json on leaflet using Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, leaflet

I need to load json from geoserver to a leaflet map. But I'm getting few errors. Below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:1000px; height:700px" id="map"></div>
  <script>
      var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        { attribution: 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' }
        );

      //create map object
      var map = new L.Map('map', {
          center: [37, -88.3],
          zoom: 5,
          layers: [osm]
      });

      var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON();

      function getJson(data) {
          console.log(data)
          geojsonLayer.addData(data);
      }

      $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geospoc/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Geospoc:ABHI_new&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json&format_options=JSON_CALLBACK",
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonpCallback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
          success: getJson
          //crossDomain: true
      })

      map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting

> ows:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

If I give the datatype as only json, Im getting -

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geospoc/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&reque…poc:ABHI_new&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json&format_options=JSON_CALLBACK.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: have you enabled JSONP in GeoServer ?